# How can I extract only horizontal or vertical line after processing in Canny Edge with OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

This is what I've reached so far. It just does Canny Edge filtering.

```
override fun onCameraFrame(inputFrame: CvCameraViewFrame): Mat? {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba()

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgbaFiltered, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    val mMat = Mat()

    Imgproc.Canny(mRgbaFiltered, mMat, threshold.toDouble(), threshold * 3.toDouble())

    return mMat
}
```

On top of that, I'd like to extract only vertical or horizontal lines.

Forget about the vertical lines. But at least, I'd like to extract the horizontal lines.
It should detect even like 15 degrees as horizontal lines. And then, If it's not horizontal enough, then, I'd like to show vertical lines of each line instead. After that, I'd like to count the number of horizontal lines. How can I accomplish this implementation?

Comment: Make two copies of image and try Hough Line Transform with your chosen angles as detection limit. In one image detect vertical and in another horizontal lines. Then count the contours in each image.

Comment: Could you clarify this sentence? it doesn’t make any sense to me: “And then, If it's not horizontal enough, then, I'd like to show vertical lines of each line instead.”

Comment: Since the screen is landscape, when I use the app horizontal becomes vertical in landscape aspect. For example, when you take a photo of a stack of cards, The height is longer. But the screen is a landscape mode. And I wanna count the number of cards by counting lines. However, the edges of cards are not always horizontal or vertical. I'd like to count the lines even if it is like 15'.

Comment: Create a horizontal and vertical kernel using `getStructuringElement` then `morphlogyEx` with `MORPH_OPEN` to create your horizontal and vertical masks, respectively